# Handling Windows Form Popups in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Automation in Selenium C#!

Im writing a test which involves clicking a button and uploading a file from a local harddrive.

I want to be able to close the windows explorer pop up that shows, i know selenium cant handle this very well, i was wondering if anyone has an knowledge of this?

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to click on the browse button.
Simply `SendKeys` it the file path then perform the save/upload operation.

```
    //browseButton here refers to the browse button element
      browseButton.SendKeys(fileToBeUploadedPath);
      saveButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The pop up could be an Alert.

Check that code in c#

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();                                        
alert.Accept();
```